# Kong service with POST request to Lambda function and JSON payload

Tags: node.js, lambda, kong

I'm just starting with Kong and setup a Lambda plugin on a service to try things out. The Lambda function I use had a simple method to parse the JSON body:

```
const getBody = (event: any): IBody => {
  const body = JSON.parse(event.body)
  return new Body(body)
}
```

So, although I was able to call the function and get a response from it, all I got was an error message similar to:

> {"status":500,"message":"SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON
>   at position 0"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is due the fact a Lambda request is [different when invoked from the cli and when called from AWS API Gateway](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491132/request-body-serialization-differences-when-lambda-function-invoked-via-api-gate).

Basically `event.body` is only available when calling from the API Gateway, whilst when called from the cli, the correct property name is `event.request_body`.

So modifiying the method to the one below will allow me to receive calls both from AWS API Gateway and cli:

```
const getBody = (event: any): IBody => {
  const body = JSON.parse(Object.is(event.request_body, undefined) ? event.body : event.request_body)
  return new Body(body)
}
```